# Access MSSQL Db from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, linked-server

I have recently read a MYSQL DB in MSSQL via creating a linked server. Does it work the other way round? I need to read MSSQL DB from MySQL. 
Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an odbc connection: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access.html

Comment: Hello Endo,
This example is not relevant to my question. It shows Access DB not SQL DB